# Formatting VGA info to conky

Tags: linux, scripting, conky

I'm trying get conky working on my system, and I'm stuck on how to format a specific shell variable to display my VGA.
From shell I get my VGA using:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

The output:

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G71M [GeForce Go
>   7900 GS] (rev a1)

For my goal I need have this output formatted for something like:
(The contents inside of [])

> GeForce Go 7900 GS

The idea is this should be dynamic for every user (I`m not willing to hard-code it).

The second output is about the current driver.
I`m getting the info from this output:

```
glxinfo | more | grep "renderer string"
```

This last one works pretty nice with:

```
${voffset 2}${font StyleBats:size=10}${color2}d${voffset -2}${font DroidSans:size=8.6}${color3}${offset 5}nVidia GeForce 7600 GT${alignr}${font DroidSans:size=8.3}${pre_exec glxinfo | more | grep 'renderer string' | awk -F':' '{print $2}'}${font}
```

The output:

> Gallium 0.4 on NV49

If I find how to format the first variable, the final output will be:

> GeForce Go 7900 GS Gallium 0.4 on NV49

Thanks in advice!!!

Comment: `lspci | awk -F'[][]' '/VGA/{print $2}'`...

Comment: Worked!!!

Thank you very much.
I have tested this one and worked too:

lspci | grep VGA | awk -F'[' '{print $2}' | awk -F']' '{print $1}'

But, yours command seems very better!!!

Comment: Yes, Awk has pattern matching so the grep is redundant...

Comment: How can I set your answer as correct? There no option for it

Answer (score 0):

```
lspci | awk -F'[][]' '/VGA/{print $2}'
```

Where the field separator is set as `[` and `]` and the pattern is `VGA`, print the second field (ie., the match between `[..]`.